# How can I use method abstraction for checking userInput against login details?

Tags: java

We worked progressively on a project. Last milestone is dividing this into the following: Create a class with four methods: main method, a method for creating customer information(void), a method for creating user name and password (void) and finally a method for log-in(return type).

I have implemented the log-in method, when moving to implementation of the `loginDetails`, I ran into problems. I don't understand how I can create `loginDetails` in a void method, and also be able to check against it in a different method. My `loginDetail` method is not returning a value to main, and my variables are local for the methods.

**How can I create the user details in a void method, and be able to create the login check in a separate method?**

This is my code, I would like to use the details generated in `loginDetails();` as the values to check against instead of the manually inserted strings.

```
public class Customer {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        loginDetails("testtest", "testtest", "11111121111");
        System.out.print(logIn("ABC", "212"));
    }

    public static void customerInformation() {
//Create customerInformation
    }

    public static void loginDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String number) {
        String userName, password;

        userName = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 3);
        password = lastName.substring(0, 3) + number.substring(7);

    }

    public static String logIn(String userName, String password) {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 3) {
            System.out.print("Input Username");
            String inputUserName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Input password");
            String inputPassword = input.nextLine();

            if (inputUserName.equals(userName) && inputPassword.equals(password)) {
                return "You are now logged in";
            } else {
                count++;
                if (count < 3)
                    System.out.println("Wrong Username or password. Try again");
            }
        } //While
        return "Try again in a few hours"; //Third try
    } //logIn
}
```

Comment: You either use instance variables or actually return something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Customer {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String userName=null;
    static String password=null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        loginDetails("testtest", "testtest", "11111121111");
        System.out.print(logIn("ABC", "212"));
    }

    public static void customerInformation() {
//Create customerInformation
    }

    public static void loginDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String number) {

        userName = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 3);
        password = lastName.substring(0, 3) + number.substring(7);

    }

    public static String logIn(String userName, String password) {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 3) {
            System.out.print("Input Username");
            String inputUserName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Input password");
            String inputPassword = input.nextLine();

            if (inputUserName.equals(userName) && inputPassword.equals(password)) {
                return "You are now logged in";
            } else {
                count++;
                if (count < 3)
                    System.out.println("Wrong Username or password. Try again");
            }
        } //While
        return "Try again in a few hours"; //Third try
    } //logIn
}
```

Comment: I have a strange feeling that that exercise is to force people to use instance fields and store state in fields to be used in other method, as return type is restricted to be void.

Comment: Yeah.. He can do it by using instance fields also

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski - I believe so, we have not worked nearly enough with arrays yet for the above answer to make sense..

Comment: @FallAndLearn - how would you do it with instance fields?

Comment: The downvote seems to be a bit harsh to me. How will I come to know that whether the OP has studied arrays or not in his/her class.

Comment: @FallAndLearn AMAZING! And I just got what instance fields do. Thanks so much! The array solution was prettier, but I am sure ill get there soon :)

Comment: @FallAndLearn I don't normally do this, but I think the down vote is indeed harsh. There are many ambiguities to questions like this, and if anything the question might deserve the down vote more--because many solutions exist for the question. People are very quick to down vote anything and it is hard to answer beginner questions without correctly assuming what the beginner has been exposed to. You get an up vote from me.

Comment: @The_Chad: Thanks. Appreciated

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I considered it because of the original solution using arrays to return multiple values. In some languages (e.g., languages that support tuples and/or trivial destructuring) it's an acceptable approach, but in Java, IMO, it's a *strong* anti-pattern. People *are* quick to downvote, but in my experience it's rarely without reason. IMO your original answer was sub-par: it was code-only (e.g., no explanation) and didn't follow Java best practices. That's grounds for a legitimate downvote. People don't always keep checking to see if things have improved.